# Database composite PK - how to make a FK appropriately?

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys

I'm doing a SQL project. When I declared the foreign keys, I came to a question. Can partial key (the attribute is part of primary key) be a foreign key?

EDIT: Thanks for the help from you all. I think i just solved the problem. But i have a new issue. if t1(a, b, c)and the primary key of t1 is(a,b), then how other table's FK points to this table?

Comment: Please retitle your question.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that your primary key is made of of two fields (a, b).  Either a or b can be foreign keys pointing to other tables.  But if another table has a FK pointing to your table you need a composite FK in the other table with both (a, b).

Comment: great! that's what i want to know. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, if the attribute is *guaranteed to uniquely identify a record in the primary table.*  But, if it meets that guarantee, then why isn't it already being used as the actual primary key?

To avoid a lot of headaches, I suggest that you use a data type that automatically generates  incrementing numbers as your primary key, and declare that key as your foreign key in the related tables.  Most relational databases already have a numeric type that fits this description.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. but in one of tables in my database, all the attributes combine together as a primary key. Then how can i reference this table to other tables?

Comment: By treating the attributes as a composite key.  But my suggestion still stands; you should be using a "row serial number" for a primary key, not a combination of fields.

Answer (score 0):

If the table you are talking about is the right side of a foreign key - yes. If the composite PK table is the left side of the FK - then the other table must have to match the composite key.

If you have table `tbl_1` with PK (`col1`, `col2`) and `tbl_2` with column `col3`, you can have FK from `tbl_2.col3` to `tbl_1.col2` for instance, (as long as types match and `tbl_2.col3` is unique) but not from `tbl_1.col2` to `tbl_2.col3`

---

**Edit**

If the situation is having a table (`tbl_1`) with composite PK that should have a foreign key to other table, you either have to make the other table contain all columns so it can form the combination of the `tbl_1`'s PK, or change `tbl_1`'s PK. Assuming `tbl_1.col1` and `tbl_1.col2` form the PK for `tbl_1`, you can change it by making an unique constraint of `tbl_1.col1` and `tbl_1.col2`, and adding single column `tbl_1.pk` that you make the PK.

Most ORM solutions recommend avoiding composite keys - make them unique instead, and use single PK column - usually `integer` or `long/bigint`. Thus, you will make relationships more easily and performance of PK will be better for single numeric column.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understand what you mean. but if the situation is all the attributes combine together as a primary key in a table, then how can i reference this table to others?

Comment: @ShuaiZhang, check me revisiting the answer